# How do I query Azure resources for a list of ADF pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, kql

I'm documenting an Azure Data Factory with hundreds of pipelines. I would like to automate the process, perhaps with KQL, so I do not have to write down each item by hand.  How do I query Azure resources for a list of ADF pipelines?

Comment: You can use the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/list-by-factory?tabs=HTTP

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API given below to get Lists of Pipelines.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Below is the list of URI Parameters:

1. factoryName
2. resourceGroupName
3. subscriptionId
4. api-version

Sample Java Code

```
import com.azure.core.util.Context;


public final class Main {
    
   
    public static void pipelinesListByFactory(com.azure.resourcemanager.datafactory.DataFactoryManager manager) {
        manager.pipelines().listByFactory("exampleResourceGroup", "exampleFactoryName", Context.NONE);
    }
}
```

Reference - [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/list-by-factory?tabs=Java)